# I don't see CDT in eclipse-cdt

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I don't see the File -> New -> C Project after I installed eclipse-cdt under ubuntu apt-get install eclipse-cdt

I've been using eclipse-cdt for couple of years, I upgraded my ubuntu and when I open eclipse the menus don't have C/C++ options in it [ as if you installed eclipse not eclipse-cdt] so I went to install new software and downloaded cdt and it says eclipse cdt is upto date yet I dont see : http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Fgetting_started%2Fcdt_w_existing_code.htm  [ you have to go down the page or search for Creating a project and click that link ]

did it disable during precise-pelagon installation or something went wrong.

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, get a Real Disto ;-P

Then, check:

```
Window --> Open Perspective
```

or

```
Window --> Show View
```

If in neither, check:

```
Window --> Customize Perspective --> Command Groups Availability
```

Just an FYI -- Eclipse is Eclipse. CDT is just an addon plugin. You can download plain vanilla Eclipse and then go to Help --> Eclipse Marketplace and search for CDT and install the plugin. A lot of people prefer to *NOT* use the bundled distro Eclipse because they usually tweak and bloat it. I used to use the Fedora Eclipse for years until I got fed up with weird and strange things happening, which usually boiled down to me using the built in one from my package manager.

For example, the Fedora Eclipse does not include the Eclipse Marketplace by default (WHY!?!), you have to go get the plugin and install it into your Eclipse just to get the normal Eclipse features that should have been there all along. There's plenty of other examples...

Answer (score 0):

ubunut upgrade screwed eclipse [ it uninstalled my old and installed new from ubuntu repo which is not CDT!! ]

resolution : install only from : http://eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, the Eclipse from the Ubuntu package manager repo will be the Base Eclipse install with a few tweaks the Ubuntu crew thought they liked. You can always install the CDT Plugin and then your Eclipse will be back to how you are used to it. CDT is only a plugin, not a special version of Eclipse.

Comment: I understand i can install the cdt plugin from base eclipse, but ubuntu upgrade screwed up a lot of things.